# AWS cdk print dependency graph

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am using cdk (v1.96.0). Is there a way for me to print the dependency graph of the stacks?

For example, when my cdk app have cyclic references, cdk synth will fail with the following message, which prints out the stack dependency.

> Error: 'S3ConsumerStack' depends on 'S3HostStack' ("S3ConsumerStack/Access/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/test-secret-key/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/DefaultPolicy/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/test-secret-key/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/CDKMetadata/Default" depends on "S3HostStack/test-secret-key/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/test-secret-key/Alias/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/DefaultPolicy/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/test-secret-key/Alias/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/CDKMetadata/Default" depends on "S3HostStack/test-secret-key/Alias/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/test_secret/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/DefaultPolicy/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/test_secret/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/CDKMetadata/Default" depends on "S3HostStack/test_secret/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/EncryptedBucket/Key/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/DefaultPolicy/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/EncryptedBucket/Key/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/CDKMetadata/Default" depends on "S3HostStack/EncryptedBucket/Key/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/EncryptedBucket/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/DefaultPolicy/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/EncryptedBucket/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/CDKMetadata/Default" depends on "S3HostStack/EncryptedBucket/Resource", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/CDKMetadata/Default", "S3ConsumerStack/Access/DefaultPolicy/Resource" depends on "S3HostStack/CDKMetadata/Default", "S3ConsumerStack/CDKMetadata/Default" depends on "S3HostStack/CDKMetadata/Default"). Adding this dependency (S3HostStack -> S3ConsumerStack/Access/Resource.Arn) would create a cyclic reference.

Is there a way for me to print the entire dependency graph?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/301